# Computing props within a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I have an array of object - some of which need to have a property tweaked depending on their value. In a v-for loop, how do I ammend a value, is this what computed is for?

I have tried creating and accessing a computed value but I suspect I am misunderstanding the order of events here.

```js
<template>
  <v-container grid-list-md>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs6 md3 v-for="item in items" :key="item.da_id">
        <v-card>
          <v-img
            :src="item.imgUrl"
            aspect-ratio="2.75"
          ></v-img>
          <v-card-title primary-title>
            <div>
              <h3 class="headline mb-0">{{item.title}}</h3>
            </div>
          </v-card-title>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>





<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data() {
    imgUrl: {
      return ''
    }
  },
  async asyncData ({ params }) {
    let {data}  = await axios.get(`http://XXX.XXX.XXX.192:8080/api/collection/${params.id}`)
    return { items: data }
  },
  computed: {
    imgUrl(item) {
        console.log(this.items.map(item))
        return 'https://aijxxppmen.cloudimg.io/crop/500x500/tjpg/https://dartmoorpublic.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/' + this.items.file_id
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am expecting each v-card :src value to be different and based on the computed function I have created. I am getting undefined.

Comment: You call the API and assign the result to 'items'.
Can you show how is structured a single 'item'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking for a *computed property*. Computed properties are properties of the Vue instance, not of the elements in your `items` array. You will want to use a *method* instead:

```
<template>
  <v-container grid-list-md>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs6 md3 v-for="item in items" :key="item.da_id">
        <v-card>
          <v-img
            :src="imgUrl(item)"
            aspect-ratio="2.75"
          ></v-img>
          <v-card-title primary-title>
            <div>
              <h3 class="headline mb-0">{{item.title}}</h3>
            </div>
          </v-card-title>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data() {
    imgUrl: {
      return ''
    }
  },
  async asyncData ({ params }) {
    let {data}  = await axios.get(`http://XXX.XXX.XXX.192:8080/api/collection/${params.id}`)
    return { items: data }
  },
  methods: {
    imgUrl(item) {
        console.log(item)
        return 'https://aijxxppmen.cloudimg.io/crop/500x500/tjpg/https://dartmoorpublic.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/' + item.file_id
    }
  }
}
```